# Array Manipulation Hackerrank terminated due to timeout in python

Tags: arrays, python-3.x

How can I optimise follwong code?
Proper Question Here :
https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/crush/problem

```
if __name__=='__main__':
    n, m = map(int, input().split())
    list=[0]*n
    for _ in range(m) :
        a, b, k = map(int, (input().split()))
        for i in range(a-1, b):
            list[i]+=k
    list.sort();
    print(list[-1])
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem with your code except that there is no prompt message in your `input` function?

Comment: I found similar problem [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/range-update-query-chessboard-pieces/). This might help you understand the logic.

Answer (score 0):

This can be further optimized to run in O(m logm) time because we have to check the value of prefix sum at only indices.

```
if __name__=='__main__':
    n, m = map(int, input().split())
    list=[0]*(n+1)
    for _ in range(m) :
        a, b, k = map(int, (input().split()))
        list[a-1]=list[a-1]+k
        list[b] = list[b] - k;

    for i in range(1,n):
        list[i]+=list[i-1]
    print(max(list))
```